# How can i display inside a div the content of the spans in my code when i clic on them?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calculator. I have different codes that have worked but I am trying to make a [new one](http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc2oxe/).

```
function calc()
{
        for(var i = 0; i <= y.length; i++)
    {
        key+=y[i].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=key;

    }
}
```

I am trying to:

- loop trough the content of all the span tags in my code (which
  contain the key values of the calculator)
  using"document.getElementsByTagName"
- when you clic on a respective key of the calculator (ex.clic on key
  "8"),obtain the content of only that key you are clicking
- when you get the content of that key you are clicking, add it to the
  variable key="" (ex. key+="8")
- display the result in the span called "display" which is the black
  screen of the calculator. (display on the black screen the number:"8")

This program basically should just get the content of the key you are clicking on the calculator and display it on the screen.

This should be in pure javascript. I already made a [similar calculator](http://jsfiddle.net/mWX7K/1582/) by making a function for each pressed keys. **I am trying to figure out a shorter way so I don't repeat myself.**

Comment: Code update it with Salmin Skenderovic solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc2oxe/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by adding an eventlistener to the document.
Then we just get info from the target clicked. 
(Not all functionality is done yet in this example).

[JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8oeehm0y/)

```
//get number key values
var key = "";

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){

  switch (e.target.id) {
    case 'eq':
      calculate(key);
      return;

    case 'mult':
      key += "*";
      break;

    case 'dvd':
      key += "/";
      break;

    default:
    key += e.target.innerHTML;
    break;
  }
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = key;
});

//calculate result
function calculate(equation) {
    var answer = eval(equation);
    key = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the command eventlistener more efficent in the code than the for loop? Also, do you know why the first code doesnt work?

Comment: Yes, since you are adding an eventlistener you are only subscribing to the event "click". Meaning, no code is ran untill an event is triggered.

Once you click somewhere, we can fetch the target of the click, and grab its inner html.

Your code above doesn't work because you are trying to fetch:
`x.getElementsByTagName("span");`

Where x is another div.

Comment: My last comment was wrong. Your code above doesn't work because you set the javascript in the head, and x is defined before the body is rendered to the DOM. Try changing the settings to the top left in JS-fiddle (change it to -in body)

Comment: Oh thats great! again thank you so much. Sorry if i ask another question but is it a problem if the HTML document has several ID? thats why i was trying to get the elements by the span tag, to avoid using too many ID  tags.

Comment: the whole html can have several IDs. The IDs should be unique tho. You can use classes instead if you want duplicates.
And don't forget to upvote my solution if you find it helpful :)

Comment: I updated the code with your solution:http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc2oxe/8/. Thank you again, but i was wondering why when i open the website on my phone it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the document-event listener not working correctly on your phone on Js-fiddle. Try pressing share and copy the full screen link and open it on your phone